Certificate verification failed during sudo apt upgrade
I'm encountering an issue when running the sudo apt upgrade command on my system after updating to Ubuntu 22.04. Below are the error logs:
Terminal error logs:

Software Updater error:

It seems like the certificate verification is failing due to the certificate not being trusted and the name in the certificate not matching the expected. I've tried updating the package lists and upgrading the packages, but the issue persists.

There is a potential security issue in https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ in your software sources that is generating the error messages. If you don't trust this software source you should remove it from your software sources by starting the line with a # character which has the effect of commenting that line out.
